# How do you use output redirection in combination with here-documents and cat?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, cat, here-document

Let's say I have a script that I want to pipe to another command or redirect to a file (piping to `sh` for the examples). Assume that I'm using bash.

I could do it using `echo`:

```
echo "touch somefile
echo foo > somefile" | sh
```

I could also do almost the same thing using `cat`:

```
cat << EOF
touch somefile
echo foo > somefile
EOF
```

But if I replace "EOF" with "EOF | sh" it just thinks that it's a part of the heredoc.

How can I make it so that `cat` outputs text from stdin, and then pipes it to an arbitrary location?

Comment: `touch` is unless there , what exactly you want ? is just read input file and redirect to another with stdout?

Comment: @RahulPatil of course it's useless. I just wanted an example with more than one line, to better illustrate the heredoc. And look at the example using `echo` - I was wondering what the equivalent of that would be using `cat`.

Comment: Your example is creating an `sh` script out of multiple strings and passing it directly to `sh` .     I found your Q looking for passing the text output of multiple commands, including a HERE document, directly to a command.  Which is what Ash's answer's 2nd example does.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.  The simplest is probably this:

```
cat <<EOF | sh
touch somefile
echo foo > somefile
EOF
```

Another, which is nicer syntax in my opinion:

```
(
cat <<EOF
touch somefile
echo foo > somefile
EOF
) | sh
```

This works as well, but without the subshell:

```
{
cat <<EOF
touch somefile
echo foo > somefile
EOF
} | sh
```

More variations:

```
cat <<EOF |
touch somefile
echo foo > somefile
EOF
  sh
```

Or:

```
{ cat | sh; } << EOF
touch somefile
echo foo > somefile
EOF
```

By the way, I expect the use of `cat` in your question is a placeholder for something else.  If not, take it out, like this:

```
sh <<EOF
touch somefile
echo foo > somefile
EOF
```

Which could be simplified to this:

```
sh -c 'touch somefile; echo foo > somefile'
```

or:

```
sh -c 'touch somefile
echo foo > somefile'
```

**Redirecting output instead of piping**

```
sh >out <<EOF
touch somefile
echo foo > somefile
EOF
```

Using `cat` to get the equivalent of `echo test > out`:

```
cat >out <<EOF
test
EOF
```

**Multiple Here Documents**

```
( cat; echo ---; cat <&3 ) <<EOF 3<<EOF2
hi
EOF
there
EOF2
```

This produces the output:

```
hi
---
there
```

Here's what's going on:

- The shell sees the `( ... )` and runs the enclosed commands in a subshell.
- The cat and echo are simple enough.  The `cat <&3` says to run cat with file descriptor (fd) 0 (stdin) redirected from fd 3; in other words, cat out the input from fd 3.
- Before the `(...)` is started, the shell sees the two here document redirects and substitutes fd 0 (`<<EOF`) and fd 3 (`3<<EOF2`) with the read-side of pipes
- Once the initial command is started, the shell reads its stdin until EOF is reached and sends that to the write-side of the first pipe
- Next, it does the same with EOF2 and the write-side of the second pipe

Comment: given the second-to-last example, can you give an example with stdout redirection instead of piping?

Comment: I editted the answer with a redirect example; is this the form you wanted editted?  If not, can you just give the first line of that part to clarify?

Comment: It may help to understand how the shell processes this.  When it's evaluating the command-line and finds the <<EOF, it then reads from standard input until either a line with only EOF is found, or end-of-input.  Everything else on the original command-line that has yet been unprocessed then continues to process.  So, for example, it's possible to do something like this: `(cat; echo ---; exec <&3; cat) <<EOF 3<<EOF2 >out` and then give that command input with two here-blocks in a row.

Comment: Your explanation of shell processing was interesting but over my head :) What I wanted to know was what would be the `cat` equivalent of `echo test > out` would be, using a heredoc. Whereas your given example added a redirection at the end of the pipe.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I know the bash manpage is very long, but it's useful to read and understand.  I'll give you the equivalent for that command in another edit.

Comment: No problem. I understood the concepts, I just couldn't follow your example.

Comment: Would you like to see a full example that you can try?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10351/discussion-between-strugee-and-ash)

Comment: @ash: i'd be interrested in seing an example with multiple heredocs (I never heard of this before today)... how do you stack them?

Comment: @OlivierDulac - I added the multiple heredoc example to the answer.

Comment: @don_crissti - thanks; I commented on that question.  Looks like the Op may have a simpler approach without using here docs.

Comment: [Instead of using cat and I/O redirection it might be useful to use tee instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17093489/717124)

Comment: Agreed - where tee does the job, it's a good approach.

Comment: @ash Is there a way to make the 2 heredocs work as an input to a command like diff? ie to accomplish `diff <heredoc1> <heredoc2>`

Comment: Tricky.  You could do something like this: `exec 98<<!
1
2
3
!

exec 99<<!
1
3
!

diff /dev/fd/98 /dev/fd/99
`

Comment: That gets squashed when inlined.

Comment: @Cole: Here, do this: `diff /dev/fd/98 /dev/fd/99 98<<! 99<<!` then follow with the two here-docs terminated by `!` each

Comment: @ash Hmm, no dice for me (using bash).  I get `/tmp/sh-thd.{-larZPk-}{+gD04GI+} (deleted)`   I've also tried it with process substitution and got: `pipe:[6255284{-2-}{+4+}]`

Comment: @ash Actually I lied, this appears to work with regular `diff` but not `git diff` I was hoping to use `git diff --color-words` for it's word level diff but it looks like I might be out of luck.

Comment: @Cole there are word-level diff tools.  It's been a while - maybe `wdiff`?

Answer (score 5):

I just want to point out that using `meow` is just as valid as `EOF`.

This script will append `Meow!` to a file named `cat`:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat <<meow>> cat
Meow!
meow
```

Save as `cats` and make it executable with `chmod +x cats`, then run it with `./cats`:

```
$ ./cats
$ cat cat
Meow!
$ ./cats
$ cat cat
Meow!
Meow!
```

**Explanation:**

- `cat <<meow` is the *here document* syntax. It instructs the script to pick up the block of text that follows this line, until it encounters the string `meow`. The contents will then be outputted (or piped along).
- `>> cat` pipes to the file named `cat`.
- Using `>` instead of `>>` would overwrite the file instead of appending to it.
- `Meow!` is the contents of the *here document*.
- `meow` is the end marker for the *here document*. The contents are, with the use of `>>`, appended to `cat`.

**Piping both to stdout and to a file:**

To do the piping you request, no *here document* is required.

`cat` can not both output text and pass the text along, but `tee` is a perfect match for what you are asking for:

```
echo echo | tee tee
```

This will both output the string `echo` and write `echo` to a file named `tee`.

You could also pass the output through `cat`, if that is part of the requirement, either with:

```
echo echo | tee tee | cat </dev/stdin
```

Or just:

```
echo echo | tee tee | cat
```

Contents of file:

```
$ cat tee
echo
```

Comment: @strugee, `>` can create pipes in `zsh` when the same fd is redirected several times as in `echo foo >&1 > tee` or `echo foo > tee | cat`, where `zsh` implements an internal `tee` to feed the output of `echo` to both `cat` and the `tee` file.

Comment: Good point. The most common marker I've seen is `!`

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add a variant to this, which was useful to me for handling a case where I needed to run a list of elements through a pipe to a `while` loop:

```bash
cat <<EOF | while read -r FOO; do
bar
baz
quux
EOF

echo $FOO

done
```

Could also be written without the cat

```bash
while read -r FOO; do
  echo $FOO
done <<EOF
bar
baz
quux
EOF
```