# Grep command using contents of a heredoc

Tags: shell, grep, pipe, ps, here-document

I'm creating a script to update a remote computer and I want to know if any user is using the computer before I update. I have a list of users and I created a heredoc with all of them. The command I'm trying to make look something like this:

```
ps -ef | grep -f | cat <<- END
    user1
    user2
    user3
END
```

Which doesn't work. What can I do to be able to filter the ps command based on my user list using a heredoc?

Comment: Switch order: `cat <<-END | grep -f- <(ps -ef)` See also [How do you use output redirection in combination with here-documents and cat?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88490)

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Can you post it as an answer and also explain why the -f- and the <() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: **`ps -u user1,user2,user3`**

---

Your `grep` command is incomplete since the `-f` option requires an argument. Your `cat` command is receiving its input from the here document, so even if you fixed the `grep` command, its output would be discarded.

If you were looking for a hard-coded user, you'd use

```
ps -ef | grep alice
```

(except that this isn't a good way to do it as I'll explain later). The input to `grep` is the output of `ps -ef`. You can pass multiple search patterns by passing multiple `-e` options:

```
ps -ef | grep -e alice -e bob
```

This prints lines containing `alice` or `bob`. To get the list of inputs from a file, you can use the `-f` option, but that requires a file name.

```
cat <<EOF >users.txt
alice
bob
END
ps -ef | grep -f users.txt
```

Standard input is already taken for the text that you're filtering, so you can't reuse it for the search pattern. Wanting multiple inputs is a common problem, so some shells (ksh, bash, zsh) offer a solution: [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) (which is what [don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti) suggested in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278402/grep-command-using-contents-of-a-heredoc#comment483974_278402)):

```
ps -ef | grep -f <(cat <<END
alice
bob
END
)
```

This approach is useful if the list of users is generated by a complex command, but with a hard-coded list, it's unnecessarily complex: `grep -e alice -e bob` does the same job.

---

The problem with this approach is that it matches user names anywhere on the line. The `ps` command has an option to list only the processes of a specific set of users. Just use that.

```
ps -u alice,bob
```

If you're on an embedded system with a version of `ps` that doesn't support `-u`, see if it supports `-o USER`, and use `grep -x` to match the whole line.

```
busybox ps -o user | grep -x -e alice -e bob
```

Answer (score 1):

In general I would recommend the [answer by Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278471/72597).

If you need your script to be POSIX compatible and your `ps` does not support `-u`, this could work:

```
ps -ef | grep -e \
"^smtpd
^dbus
^ntp"
```

I.e. pipe the output of `ps -ef` through `grep -e pattern_list`. The pattern_list is supplied as a multiline-string, each pattern starts with `^` to anchor it at the beginning of a line.