# What are the steps needed to cache passphrases entered via pinentry using gpg-preset-passphrase in 2.1.15?

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent

I'm seeking to cache passphrases for use on an unattended machine. As doing this poses some risk, I'd prefer choosing which passphrases get cached and avoid setting both `default-cache-ttl` and `max-cache-ttl` to obnoxiously high values as well as avoid needing to clear `gpg-agent`'s entire cache periodically - hence I'm looking for a solution with `gpg-preset-passphrase`. Some of the information I found while troubleshooting refer to older versions of GnuPG so I'm unsure if I have sufficiently accounted for all the differences.

First, as prescribed by `man 1 gpg-agent`, I have `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` in my .bashrc.

Now suppose I run `eval $(gpg-agent --daemon --allow-preset-passphrase --default-cache-ttl 1 --max-cache-ttl 31536000)` to start gpg-agent, noting that [gpg-preset-passphrase still honors --max-cache-ttl](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/gpg_002dpreset_002dpassphrase.html) (default 2 hours).

I then get the keygrip `$KEYGRIP` of the desired secret subkey with `gpg --with-keygrip -K`.

With that I try `/path/to/gpg-preset-passphrase -c $KEYGRIP`. Upon hitting return, this prints:

```
   gpg-preset-passphrase: caching passphrase failed: Not implemented
```

Attempting again adding `--verbose --debug 6 --log-file /path/to/gpg-agent.log` to `gpg-agent`, my log is appended with

```
   gpg-agent[4206] listening on socket /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent
   gpg-agent[4207] gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.1.15 started
   gpg-agent[4207] handler 0x7f86ef783700 for fd 5 started
   gpg-agent[4207] command PRESET_PASSPHRASE failed: Not implemented
   gpg-agent[4207] handler 0x7f86ef783700 for fd 5 terminated
```

I'm unsure where to proceed from this apart from diving deeper into the source, so I'm wondering if anyone can first correct the steps I'm taking.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I'm marginally sure the passphrase has to be sent to stdin of `gpg-preset-passphrase`, my first concrete lead on that is from this mailing list https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2010-January/037876.html

Comment: how to send it from stdin, instead of echo? this doens't sound secure at all

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to send the passphrase to `gpg-preset-passphrase` over stdin, *without* echoing it (to avoid exposing it in process list):

```
/path/to/gpg-preset-passphrase -c $KEYGRIP <<< $PASSPHRASE
```

If you care about portability outside of bash:

```
/path/to/gpg-preset-passphrase -c $KEYGRIP <<EOF
$PASSPHRASE
EOF
```

This answer about "Here Documents" syntax (EOF) was invaluable to me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88492

You also need `allow-preset-passphrase` in your `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` as mentioned by holms.

If you're looking to do this with symmetric encryption (since I already lost my sanity to this, maybe you won't have to), see my answer here w.r.t. finding the right keygrip/cacheid to use to preset the passphrase in gpg-agent: https://superuser.com/a/1485486/1093343

Comment: The `-c` is not mentioned anywhere. I think you meant to use `--preset`

Comment: @smac89 It's mentioned in the usage docs from `/path/to/gpg-preset-passphrase --help` (in my installation at least), this outputs `-c, --preset              preset passphrase`. So `-c` is synonymous with `--preset` here, I used it for parity with the original question which uses `-c`.

Answer (score 0):

I've also got this problem and I've solved by adding configuration to gpg-agent, you can find it in here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491679/how-to-enter-gnupg-agent-key-passhprase-from-cli