# A script that is executed fine from file breaks when executed with Heredoc (in PHPmyadmin installation)

Tags: shell-script, prompt, crash, here-document, phpmyadmin

I can run the following script just fine using the traditional way of:

```
cd ~ && vi script.sh [PASTE SCRIPT INSIDE] && chmod +x script.sh && ./script.sh && rm -rf script.sh
```

Yet, if I execute the exact same script with Heredoc (to just paste and execute directly from Bash prompt), then the script will be executed only partially, and will break before the end.

For example, ere's what happens when I run the following script with Heredoc:

The PHPmyadmin install interface fuses with the CLI, while the CLI itself loses almost any capability besides documenting standard input:

[image]

### The script (with my Heredoc):

```
bash << 'EOT0'

#!/bin/bash -x

# Setup LAMP environment with enabled mod rewrite:
cd ~
apt-get install lamp-server^ -y
a2enmod rewrite
cat << EOF >> /etc/apach2/apache2.conf
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
EOF
service apache2 restart

# Setup Webmin and some dependencies:
apt-get install unzip perl libnet-ssleay-perl openssl libauthen-pam-perl libpam-runtime libio-pty-perl apt-show-versions python -y
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.810_all.deb
dpkg --install webmin_1.810_all.deb
apt-get -f install
sed -i 's/ssl=1/ssl=0/g' /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf
/etc/init.d/webmin restart

# Cron tasks:
echo -e "\07" && echo -e "\007" # Choose Nano (2) and do ^x.
USER=benqzq
crontab -u $USER -l 2>/dev/null
cat <<- 'EOF'
0 8 * * *  tar -zcvf /home/USERNAME/backups/files/www-html-$(date +\%F-\%T-).tar.gz /var/www/html
0 8 * * *  find /home/USERNAME/backups/files/* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;

0 8 * * *  mysqldump -u root -PASSWORD --all-databases > /home/USERNAME/backups/mysql/alldb_backup.sql
1 8 * * *  tar -zcvf /home/USERNAME/backups/mysql/alldb_backup-$(date +\%F-\%T-).sql.tar.gz /home/USERNAME/backups/mysql/alldb_backup.sql
2 8 * * *  rm /home/USER/backups/mysql/alldb_backup.sql
2 8 * * *  find /home/USERNAME/backups/mysql/* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
EOF
crontab -e
USER=root

# Setup PMA:
echo -e "\07" && echo -e "\007"
apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mb\string php-gettext -y
phpenmod mcrypt && phpenmod mbstring
bash -c "echo 'Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf' >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf"
systemctl reload apache2.service

# Setup Fail2Ban:
apt-get install fail2ban -y

# Secure PMA HTTP authentication from BFAs with Fail2Ban:
cat << EOF > /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/phpmyadmin.conf
[Definition]
denied = mysql-denied|allow-denied|root-denied|empty-denied
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*(?:%(denied)s)$
ignoreregex =
EOF
cat << EOF >> /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
[phpmyadmin]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = phpmyadmin
logpath = /var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin_access.log
EOF

service  apache2 reload
service fail2ban reload
reboot

# Comment1
# Comment2
# Comment3
# ...

EOT0
```

### Update for Stéphane Chazelas

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing:

```
bash << 'EOT'
some-command-that-reads-stdin
EOT
```

But `some-command-that-reads-stdin`'s stdin will be that here document as well, as it is started by `bash` so inherits the same `stdin`.

You could do:

```
bash /dev/fd/3 3<< 'EOT'
some-command-that-reads-stdin
EOT
```

So stdin is left untouched, and `bash` gets the code from that here document on another fd.

Comment: 3 3? I know that fd is a file-device but what is 3 space 3? As I'm very new to Unix, I would thank you for a didactic explanation on this.

Comment: `/dev/fd/3` refers to the file descriptor numbered 3 and is the input to `bash`, just like you would have `bash script.sh`. You may be familiar with 0, 1, and 2 already (stdin, stdout, and stderr). Then `3<<` uses the heredoc for file descriptor 3.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably using the wrong shell. I would remove the empty line between the `bash << 'EOT0'` and `#!/bin/bash -x`.

You could add this line to check which shell gets used:

```
echo $SHELL >/tmp/shell.txt
```

Then check the result with a simple cat:

```
cat /tmp/shell.txt
```

Comment: cat shows /bin/bash... I never installed another shell besides the native Ubuntu Bash...

Comment: `dash` (and a soft link to it as `sh`) is always installed. It is important for many parts of Unix to run. Anyway, I guess that's something else if the `$SHELL` variable says `bash`...

Comment: Just noting that removing the empty row between them didn't help... But please take a look at Stéphane's answer that worked for me.