# What is the meaning of the 3 3 in bash /dev/fd/3 3<< 'EOF'

Tags: here-document

There is a Unix code I saw and don't have enough background to fully dechipher:

```
bash /dev/fd/3 3<< 'EOF'
```

What is the meaning of `3 3` above? I know what is an heredoc, what is Bash, a device, and fd, but I don't know what is **3 space 3**... When I searched the phrase quoted in Google I found basically nothing.

The code was given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323797/a-script-that-is-executed-fine-from-file-breaks-when-executed-with-heredoc) as a special heredoc that allows running scrips in-place (specifically those that already include internal heredocs and comments), without creating a file with suitable permissions...

Can a Unix master please explain what is the `3 3` part? Thank you,

Comment: where did you see this? you have to give context for people to understand the question.

Comment: I've expanded the question and gave as much as details I saw as needed to touch that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That phrase is a way of passing a here-doc to `bash` on a file descriptor other than 0. I.e., 3.

The first part of the phrase, `base /dev/fd/3`, runs `bash` with file descriptor 3 as its input, and the second part, `3<< EOF`, tells the shell to write the here-doc into that file descriptor.

Note that `3<<` must be a single token, without spacing.

By doing this, any stdin reading within the here-doc script will read true input (from file descriptor 0), and not the here-doc itself. As I understand it, without doing something like this, the here-doc ends up being stdin for the inner bash, and in that case it cannot read "true input".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. **File descriptor? Rather than 0?** I have no idea what these mean and can go read on it right now but I humbly suggest you would add a parenthesis-level description of these two concepts for future readers...

Comment: @Benia http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256599/what-are-file-descriptors-explained-in-simple-terms

Comment: @muru I have read there passionately and discovered how OS's tend to organize process in trees/tables/u's and attach each file entry in the process these integer file descriptors starting from 1. Yet, I still fail to make the association between the number 3 in the following context --- Why is it 3 and not 2 or 1 (if not 0)... I believe that a clarification that could help and any other newcomer to understand the answer right here on this page, without longer learning outside and then coming back.

Comment: I think the story is: The "3" comes from that "3<<" allocates that file descriptor for piping the text to, and then the fd3 gets inherited to the child, who reads it. You could use any free number, say "8<<" and would then need to refer to /dev/fd/8 accordingly.

Comment: I suggest to anyone which is new to Linux to read in the following session if something didn't make sense above, and then read here again: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358022/is-it-true-to-conclude-that-there-are-4-types-of-output-we-can-reference-to